# How do I limit the maximum height of an image in signatures?

Tags: 6

Is there a way to automatically set the maximum allowed height of images in the [Signatures for Forums](https://drupal.org/project/signature_forum) module for Drupal 6? This will greatly help to have a tidy forum.

Answer (score 0):

[image]Under 
Home >> Administration >> Site Configuration 
Go to **Signatures for Forums**
Inside template for signature you can set the height inside the div as follows :

```
<div style= "height : 100px;">%s</div>
```

Home >> Administer >> User Management

Go to Picture Support option and enable it

After that you will find a field **Picture maximum dimensions:** where you can set your image maximum height and width
 check the image link[image]

Comment: This is a good idea to limit the total height of the signature. However the problem remains that when the image height is more than 100px, it goes over the next post. Do you have any idea to limit the img height within the < div > ?

Comment: check the updates in the answer @alfish

Comment: I had already set the 'Picture maximum dimensions' field but that applies to avatars not signature images.

Comment: How do you add images here in this module?

Comment: people add images from different sources, like the very site's IMCE, or external image hostings.